# Computer Vision: Masking a human hand

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I'd like to detect my hand from a live video stream and create a mask of my hand. However I'm reaching quite a poor result, as you can see from the picture.

My goal is to track the hand movement, so what I did was convert the video stream from BGR to HSV color space then I thresholded the image in order to isolate the color of my hand, then I tried to find the contours of my hand although the final result isn't quite what I wanted to achieve.

How could I improve the end result?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cam = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
cam.set(3,640)
cam.set(4,480)
ret, image = cam.read()

skin_min = np.array([0, 40, 150],np.uint8)
skin_max = np.array([20, 150, 255],np.uint8)    
while True:
    ret, image = cam.read()

    gaussian_blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(image,(5,5),0)
    blur_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(gaussian_blur, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

#threshould using min and max values
    tre_green = cv2.inRange(blur_hsv, skin_min, skin_max)
#getting object green contour
    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(tre_green,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

#draw contours
    cv2.drawContours(image,contours,-1,(0,255,0),3)

    cv2.imshow('real', image)
    cv2.imshow('tre_green', tre_green)   

    key = cv2.waitKey(10)
    if key == 27:
        break
```

Here the link with the pictures: https://picasaweb.google.com/103610822612915300423/February7201303.
New link with image plus contours, mask, and original.
https://picasaweb.google.com/103610822612915300423/February7201304

And here's a sample picture from above:

[image: Sample picture of a torso with arms ... and a hand]

Comment: Include the sample video you are having trouble with, otherwise it is pointless to try to guess what you are actually working with.

Comment: I can't upload the pictures, since I don't have enough reputation points :(

Comment: Just include a link. And include link to the /video/, not individual frames.

Comment: It's a live stream. Do you want a sample of it?

Comment: I don't know what is that, just include a sample of what you are working with.

Comment: Probably __live__ stream, I guess.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo I just put the link with the images.

Comment: I added one of the images (the smaller one).

Comment: @user1979084 by live stream do you mean you are recording it with some camera ? You can easily create a video from that using opencv. Do that and include a link to it.

Comment: @mmgp I'm not recording it's done on the fly...

Comment: @user1979084 ... what I'm telling you is to record it ...

Comment: @mmgp I don't see why recording it would be helpful.

Comment: This isn't really a SO type of question; you're straying into the woods of complex algorithm questions.

Comment: @katrielalex I'm not really asking for a better algorithm, I just don't know which one should I use to obtain a better mask... or perhaps better HSV values for recognising skin colors in opencv.

Comment: @katrielalex huh ? It is helpful since I (or anyone interested in giving an answer) have the actual data available, it is completely useful.

Comment: @mmgp I can post the pictures if you like with the original(not_modified)? would that be helpfull?

Comment: @user1979084 better than nothing, but I don't get why you just don't record it and post a link for that. If that is because you don't know how to use the `VideoWriter` in opencv, check http://stackoverflow.com/a/14439455/1832154 (it almost solves this recording issue, the only difference is that you will read frames and then write as in this linked answer).

Comment: @mmgp I added the link with the origina image, image+contours, mask

Comment: @mmgp and btw, you are right I don't know know how to use VideoWriter :(

Comment: @user1979084 the link doesn't work, page not found.

Comment: @mmgp, sorry my bad please try now...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are many ways to perform pixel-wise threshold to separate "skin pixels" from "non-skin pixels", and there are papers based on virtually any colorspace (even with RGB). So, my answer is simply based on the paper Face Segmentation Using Skin-Color Map in Videophone Applications by Chai and Ngan. They worked with the YCbCr colorspace and got quite nice results, the paper also mentions a threshold that worked well for them:

```
(Cb in [77, 127]) and (Cr in [133, 173])
```

The thresholds for the `Y` channel are not specified, but there are papers that mention `Y > 80`. For your single image, `Y` in the whole range is fine, i.e. it doesn't matter for actually distinguishing skin.

Here is the input, the binary image according to the thresholds mentioned, and the resulting image after discarding small components.

[image] [image] [image]

```
import sys
import numpy
import cv2

im = cv2.imread(sys.argv[1])
im_ycrcb = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2YCR_CB)

skin_ycrcb_mint = numpy.array((0, 133, 77))
skin_ycrcb_maxt = numpy.array((255, 173, 127))
skin_ycrcb = cv2.inRange(im_ycrcb, skin_ycrcb_mint, skin_ycrcb_maxt)
cv2.imwrite(sys.argv[2], skin_ycrcb) # Second image

contours, _ = cv2.findContours(skin_ycrcb, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, 
        cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
for i, c in enumerate(contours):
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area > 1000:
        cv2.drawContours(im, contours, i, (255, 0, 0), 3)
cv2.imwrite(sys.argv[3], im)         # Final image
```

Lastly, there are a quite decent amount of papers that do not rely on individual pixel-wise classification for this task. Instead, they start from a base of labeled images that are known to contain either skin pixels or non-skin pixels. From that they train, for example, a SVM and then distinguish other inputs based on this classifier.

Comment: @mmpg wow this really works astonishingly well! thanks. i had a bit of trouble while using `cv2.inRange()` but that got solved by using `min_YCrCb = numpy.array([0,133,77],numpy.uint8)` and `max_YCrCb = numpy.array([255,173,127],numpy.uint8)`

Comment: @samkhan13 :- Any reference to achieve this in iOS language

Answer (score 3):

A simple and powerful option is **histogram backprojection**. For example, create a 2D histogram using H and S (from HSV color space) or a* and b* (from La*b* color space), using pixels from different *training* images of your hand. Then use [cv2.calcBackProject][1] to classify the pixels in your stream. It's very fast and you should get 25 to 30 fps easily, I guess. Note this is a way to learn the *color distribution* of your object of interest. The same method can be used in other situations.